# skype4py PlaceCall doesn't work on OSX

Tags: python, macos, skype, skype4py

I'm trying to write a python script which calls skype numbers for a music project. For some reason although the script can connect to the skype instance, when I make a call the app just waits and the call never goes through to the calling device.

I've tried this in my own script, and the example record.py script and both don't work.

I'm using Python 2.7.10, in 32 bit mode, on OSX 10.11.6. I'm using skype4py version 1.0.35.

Does this work better on other platforms?

Comment: Why is this a bad question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this on windows 8, and osx the API seems to be broken. On ubuntu trusty, the code works exactly as expected.

Comment: In which OSX Version its not working and in Windows 10 did you tried?

Comment: El capitan and no I didn't. The problem is the API is deprecated and has merged into other windows api's. I would recommend not using this api and using a SIP provider if possible. Even on ubuntu phone calls to real numbers are not possible.